# Difference between /var/www and /srv/www in nginx

Tags: nginx, var

Recently i installed Nginx and want to change the root directory of that but i don't know  what the difference is between `/var/www` and `/srv/www` and when i should use `/var/www` or `/srv/www` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference is: different file structure. Different servers implement slightly different file structures.

Here is a good link that describes common file structures in Linux: 
[Linux Directory Structure (File System Structure) Explained with Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-file-system-structure/)

From this:

> /var – Variable Files
>
> ```
> - var stands for variable files.
> - Content of the files that are expected to grow can be found under this directory.
> - This includes — system log files (/var/log); packages and database files (/var/lib);  
>   emails (/var/mail); print queues (/var/spool); lock files (/var/lock);
>   temp files needed across reboots (/var/tmp);
> ```
>
> /srv – Service Data
>
> ```
> - srv stands for service.
> - Contains server specific services related data.
> - For example, /srv/cvs contains CVS related data.
> ```

Based on that, `/srv` would seem more appropriate. However, the Ubuntu flavor of Linux for example does not generally use a `/srv` file structure and rather uses the `var` directory for `www`. So I think the key is being consistent with the OS you use.

Comment: Actually, Ubuntu users are still encourage to use `/srv` too. `/var/www` is for the default, os-installed "websites" such as Apache's "It Works!" landing page. For _your_ stuff, use `/srv`

Comment: @MestreLion Says who? The default page is placed in a subdirectory and it won't be re-created after deletion. Just because you like to do it that way doesn't make it a policy.

Comment: It's not a policy, but rather a _recommendation_. The default page is shipped in Apache's `deb` package from the repositories, so it _could_ be seen as "OS-installed" stuff, just like things in `/usr`. While `/srv` is a standard location for _local_ files, which distributions and system packages should not touch. Says who? The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s17.html), and Debian and Ubuntu respect that. There's even a template for enabling `/srv/www` in the default config file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`